# I want to create time range based on the start and end time range given with 15 minutes chunks in php

Tags: php, date, time

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
$pdts       =   array();
$uri        =   "http://admin.migaprint.com/api/estimated-time/575";        
$obj_json   =   json_decode(file_get_contents($uri));           
// current time - beginning of chunks
$begin = new DateTime();
// adjust $begin time for next '15/30/45/00' chunk
$next = $begin->format("i") % 15;
if ($next !== 0) {
    $begin->modify('+' . (15 - $next) . 'minutes');
}
// time of last chunk
$end = clone $begin;
$end->modify("+24 hours");
// chunk interval (15 minutes)
$interval = new DateInterval('PT15M');
// date / time period onject
$timeRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
//iterate time
foreach($timeRange as $time) {
    if(isset($obj_json->opening_hour_starts) && sizeof($obj_json->opening_hour_starts) > 0) {
        foreach($obj_json->opening_hour_starts as $key => $sdate) {
            $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time->format("H:i"));
            $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $obj_json->opening_hour_starts[$key]);
            $date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $obj_json->opening_hour_ends[$key]);
            if($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3) {
               $pdts[$time->format("H.i")."h"] = $time->format("H.i");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

opening_hour_starts":["19:00","23:59"],"opening_hour_ends":["23:59","01:30"]

This is how I am receiving the data from an api which gives me the start and end time in json and want to create a range like this:

**19:00**
19:15
19:30
19:45
20:00.......23:45 **23:59**     **00:00**  00:15 00:30..... **01:30**

The last condition is that I should skipe the hours < than current time

Comment: This is what I am currently doing. It is skipping hours range which lies in next day like: opening_hour_starts":["19:00","23:59"],"opening_hour_ends":["23:59","01:30"]

Comment: No this question is not the duplicate one of the one you have shared.

Comment: I need range only in 0, 15, 30, 45 for each hours and also skip the hours < than current time.

Let say from 19:00 to 23:59 and 23:59 to 01:30

Comment: There are lots of other duplicates. Do a search and extrapolate a solution form one or more of them